# Overriding ActiveRecord::Base#to_xml for parent but not children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, activerecord, overriding, builder

I have an activerecord model with some attributes that I need to override when producing xml for an API. The instructions [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_xml) describing how to write a custom `to_xml` method work fine for that.

The problem I'm having is that the model is at the top of a fairly deep system of relations, and it will be an enormous amount of work to manually specify the xml generation of all the descendants. Is there any way to hand control back to Builder for the relations, so that it can automatically produce their xml just like it did before I had to override?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
class IHaveMyOwnXML < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
  def to_xml(options = {})
    options[:indent] ||= 2
    xml = options[:builder] ||= Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent])
    xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]
    xml.level_one do
      xml.tag!(:second_level, 'content')
    end
    xml.pick_up_where_you_left_off! widgets
  end
end
```

Obviously `pick_up_where_you_left_off!` doesn't exist. What I want is for the xml for `widgets` to be injected at this point in the xml doc looking exactly like it would have if I had not done an override, and had called IHaveMyOwnXML#to_xml(:include => :widgets).

Is this possible? Or once you override ActiveRecord#to_xml, are you then committed to manually coding xml production for arbitrarily deep nested AR relations?

I've tried the first suggestion given, and while it is fine by itself, I can't tell how to inject a relation once I'm in my custom to_xml method. neither of the following work:

```
xml.household do
  xml.id id
  xml.accounts accounts
end

xml.household do
  xml.id id
  xml << accounts.to_xml # also w/ (opts.merge(:builder => xml))
end
```

The first one just gives a ruby object ref (`<accounts>#&lt;Account:0x10abb5250&gt;</accounts>`). The second one injects a complete xml document with the `household` node as the root, and an xml declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by doing something like this:

You define a method that answers if the model wants custom xml

```
# Parent
def use_custom_xml?
  true
end

# Child
def use_custom_xml?
  false
end
```

Now you can write your custom xml generator on the parent like this:

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  return super unless use_custom_xml?
  # ... your custom code
end
```

I have not tried this for xml generation but I used a similar pattern and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Initial testing seems to indicate this is going to work. I had tried this already, but it was getting confused by the initial arguments sent at the top level - `foo.to_xml(:include => {:bar => :car})` - this was getting an exception because Bar doesn't `have_any :bars`. After considering your answer, I realized that I should not be using :include when I'm defining to_xml manually b/c I am already explicitly doing `xml.bar bar`

Comment: Ok, it turns out that while this is fine, it is incomplete. I can't figure out how to inject a relation into the xml once `use_custom_xml?` is true. I have updated the question with the additional challenge.